# How to trigger program while update info in SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I want to create application which update their control properties at the time of table values updated from database by another user. i find a solution by refreshing a control every second by help of timer, but it is not good i want to change after updating a values not to request every second SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to have SQL post when the table is updated.  This called a push model (the opposite is a pull model which you are now doing).

You can use SqlDependency for this.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

However, there is some overhead associated with a push approach.  Many apps just do a query every n seconds (3 - 10) and then only update the control when the properties changed.

It really is a optimisation trade off.  Is making a network request (pull model) more "expensive" than having SQL server doing the trigger and then send the update message (push model)?

Comment: Thank You Richard Schneider it is very usefull for me making applications

Comment: Sorry there is something wrong in my project. when i try my code that is not due to this solution i forgot remove timer at the time of test. It was not working on my code so i am trying now some step may be missed i think. but i am trying your solution after stressful implementation i will accept your answer with best comments. thank you for your support @Richard

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this, without polling.

[Implementing SQL Server 2005 Query Notifications in C# Windows Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555893)